# elasticseach escape special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running the following query

```
GET myindex/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "campaign_new",
      "query": "(firtPart - Second Third)"
    }
  }
}
```

and I am getting

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

But I have values for this campaign if I do a `match_all` search, but it is not fetched by this query. I have doubt that this might be due to the escaping  issue. But when I tried `firtPart \- Second\ Third`, it is showing an error in Sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the hypen twice. I assume you are trying to do an exact match, so you only need to wrap the query in double quotes, which also needs to be escaped (quotes only need to be escaped once).

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "campaign_new",
            "query": "\"(firtPart - Second Third)\""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is also giving me the same. can you please update the answer with hyphen escaped twice ?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the hypen escaped twice.

Comment: But this also not giving me any results. But term query does. I need to use teh  query string as I need to use the 'AND' and 'OR' for comparing multiple values like "campaign_new:new_value AND network_new:new_value". Is there any other way for doing this ?

Comment: Got it I have been doing ti wrong. Accepting answer :) Thanks man